# How to move through two clips with an image in Adobe Premiere

Tags: adobe, transition, mask, adobe-premiere

I'm still new to Adobe Premiere, and my idea is the following

With **two clips**, I would like to **move from one to the other through an image that will move from left to right on the screen**, following the example I did below:

[image]

My first attempt was to use Image Masking, but if I use this effect on the Image it doesn't work, and if I do it manually in the first clip, I will have to manually make this mask every time I want to use this transition

**does anyone know a way to make this transition with the image in an efficient way?** <3

Answer (score -1):

You could create this transition manually by '[keyframing](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-add-keyframes-in-adobe-premiere-pro/)' the clips and the image to slide together.

I am sure there is a more automatic way of doing it but I am so used to keyframing at the moment so it is the first thing that comes to mind!

If you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAzMJXMmvE0) then you will get a rough idea on where to start.

When I can't find a premade transition that suits my needs, I usually just keyframe stuff manually in both Premiere and After Effects, hope this helps!